# Run SSIS package in debug mode, but eventually shows nothing, exits debug mode, and says the process is locked if I try again

Tags: ssis

I've had an issue lately with running SSIS packages.  I believe I am using the visual studio 2015 shell that comes with sql server data tools.

What will happen is that I run a long-running package, in debug mode i believe ( I always use the green arrows to start things off).  I'll come back, but the package will not longer show as running or completed.  It'll just show visual studio as if I just opened it back up.  Usually I should see a note saying that the package has executed and that I need to exit debug mode. Not the case here, so I have no idea if the packages ran, or with what errors, if any.

When I reload the project and try to run it, it will say cannot access 'because it is being used by another process.'

Any ideas of whats going on?  I'm not a developer, I just use this existing tool to migrate data from one server to another that I have more permissions on.  I like the tool, but it has been gradually getting funkier in its behavior.

Comment: Going to be difficult to provide good troubleshooting as we have no reproducible example. When the long running process seems to be hung, open up Task Manager (Ctrl-Alt-Delete) and then see whether there is a process on the Details tab named `DtsDebugHost.exe` That is what SSIS is using to run a package when you have F5/Green play button. If that's still there, then VS still thinks it's doing something related to the package. Now, I've seen situations where people have popup alert windows in SSIS packages that fire but the focus doesn't go to them so no one knows there's a box needing closed

Comment: Ok.  I'll take a look at that when I run it again.  But there is no pop-up alert window or anything.  It just appears as if vs just closed out and then reopened without any projects loaded.

Comment: So I restarted and tried again and observed VS crash without providing me an error and rebooting.  I do see two Dtsdebughost.exe running in the details tab.

Comment: If you have this problem where it says the file is locked you can do this:  kill ssisdebughost in task manager  and it will let you run the file.